# Correct Javascript syntax for concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation, foursquare

I am trying to pull locations using the foursquare API, and seemingly am not writing the syntax correctly.

```
 address = '<p><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q="' + 
 venues.location.address + '">' + 
 venues.location.address + '</p>';
```

Although this is not throwing an error, it results in the following code:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=">Correct Business Name</a>
```

The point is, the query string that google maps uses is missing, and it is showing up correctly in the link text. What am I doing wrong with my concatenation / syntax?

Comment: Look at your double quotes. You're generating this: `<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q="Correct Business Name">Correct Business Name</a>` which is an anchor tag with three new custom attributes, correct, business, and name, followed by an extra double quote.

Comment: thanks Kevin that fixed it, next time post it as an answer!

Comment: I'd rather delete it since it's just a typo.

Comment: @JCHASE11 or next time just read your own code before posting ;-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a simple typo.

Comment: Id rather give someone credit if they helped versus giving someone else credi that was slower to the punch! And I did read my own code before posting, human error!

Comment: I was just joking, sorry. My point is that I agree with @KevinB, a typo just deserves a comment, not an answer. This post is unlikely to help anybody in the future.

Comment: yes, apologies, thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, @Esailija actually provided a helpful answer with EncodeURIComponent, so I take my comment back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
address = '<p>' +
    '<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=' +
    encodeURIComponent(venues.location.address) +
    '">' +
    venues.location.address +
    '</p>';
```

Comment: is encodeURIComponent completely necessary here?

Comment: @JCHASE11 unless you have already called `encodeURIComponent` on the data then for general correctness yes. There is probably no security vulnerability but your application will definitely work incorrectly depending on the characters in an address if you leave it out.

Comment: @JCHASE11 If you left it out and the company name included a double quote, you'd run into the same issue that your typo caused.